# c# multi line strings allowing variable calling

Tags: c#

I have googled but cannot find an answer for this question:

I know about multi-line strings in c#. But how can I create a string like:

```
string temp = @"DECLARE @rolename varchar(max)
SET @rolename ='***' 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_execute',@rolename"
```

*** represents there I have to delcare a variable having some value like (object.variable).

Is this possible??

Comment: Hm, you may want to do it using a SqlParameter if possible. Injecting text into SQL queries can be a bad habit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `string.Format`:

```
string temp = @"DECLARE @rolename varchar(max)
SET @rolename ='{0}' 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_execute',@rolename";

string result = string.Format(temp, object.variable);
```

Note that you are open for sql-injection attacks if `object.variable` is (or might be in future) a user defined variable.

Comment: This is a SQL injection risk, note - depending on whether the role-name is white-listed

Comment: But will this object.variable value will fall in that exact position({0})?

Comment: whitelisted in the sense?

Comment: @vysakh If it's one of just a few allowed hard coded values, it's probably ok, if it's originating from user input and not validated, it's probably not.

Comment: It's still a bad idea.  If your code has any user input anywhere, many engineers who see this code will be inclined to waste time verifying that @rolename never comes from user input, and some engineer might later change it to use user input without fixing the injection.  Please don't use `String.Format` for this.

Comment: @Brian: Although i agree that you should always use sql-parameters if possible, it is not clear if OP is querying the database at all. He didn't mention a database or showed code where he uses ADO.NET. So maybe this is just a (bad) example or he's building something like a sql-generator tool.
So to say that you should never use `String.Format` if there is something that looks like sql is too general.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: In your example above, should the temp variable be replaced with {0} to achieve the output?

Comment: @vysakh: No, it works as it is. The `{0}` will be replaced with the first parameter, so `object.variable`. If you want to add more parameters just concatenate them and increase the value in the braces(f.e. `{1}` for the second and `{2}` for the third). Have a look at the remarks section here at **MSDN**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: @vysakh: `temp` is the complete string. It's your variable. But it can be a constant string, all occurrences of `{...}` will be replaced from `String.Format`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter:oops...sorry...so..what you say is that object.variable will replace the {0} with its value.right?

Comment: @vysakh: Yes :) Just read the tutorial on MSDN i've posted above. Here it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Answer (score 10):

.NET supports multi-line strings, sure. The `@"..."` syntax is just a shortcut to make it easier in the language. However, in your specific example you **should not** try to concatenate the value in: that entire example should be done via parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_execute',@rolename";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rolename", yourRoleName);
```

Update: checking [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx), the second parameter is actually the member-name, but you might also be able to use:

```
cmd.CommandText = "sp_addrolemember";
cmd.CommantType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rolename", "db_execute");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("membername", yourMemberName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method:

```
string temp = string.Format(@"DECLARE @rolename varchar(max)
SET @rolename ='{0}' 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_execute',@rolename", variable);
```

Comment: This is a SQL injection risk, note - depending on whether the role-name is white-listed

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible:

```
string temp = string.Format(@"DECLARE @rolename varchar(max)
SET @rolename ='{0}' 
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_execute',@rolename", variable);
```